# How to upgrade to newer version of tool in Buildroot?

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I am new to Buildroot and I am trying to figure out how to update `genimage` to newer version in Buildroot. I am currently on version 14 and I would like to update to version 15 of `genimage` tool.

Can anyone please let me know how to upgrade to newer versions of tools in Buildroot?

I found the PATCH file to bump to version 15 here : [genimage](https://lore.kernel.org/all/87wnkb30xs.fsf@dell.be.48ers.dk/T/)
But I am not sure how to apply this Patch file in Buildroot.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am using Buildroot 2021.11.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patches can simply be applied with the 'patch' tool, but you probably have Buildroot in a git repo, so you can add it as a git commit with git am  or directly cherry pick the commit with git cherry-pick . Do notice that genimage 15 does bring a few non-backwards compatible changes.
If the above sounds complicated to you, then consider just moving to the 2022.02 release which includes it. The final 2022.02 release will be out in a few days, but you can already use 2022.02-rc3.

Comment: Thank you Peter for the answer. I got a workaround with version 14 of genimage. I will upgrade to Buildroot 2022.02 release in coming days.